# 2-way databinding in autocomplete component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I have 2 input filelds:

1) courses (i,e Filter autocomplete component)
2) Amount (i,e input component) which are displayed as shown in below image:

[image]

Here i want to perform 2-way data-binding. i,e If i change `Course` name the `Amount` should change according the `Course`. How can i achieve this?

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8fmbef-up7jcm?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.ts) link.

Comment: It's not clear how the selected course relates to the amount that get's shown.

Comment: I think i have explained everything correctly in the question.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can create a dictionary of key value on component, at next way

> options: {(option:string):number} = { 'Maths': 20000, 'Physics':
>   20000, 'Biology': 20000};

Using Object.keys for get the auto-complete input and addinga selected option bindig to store selected option.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-filter-example.css'],
})
export class AutocompleteFilterExample implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: {(option:string):number} = { 'Maths': 20000, 'Physics': 20000, 'Biology': 20000};
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
  selectedOpt: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return Object.keys(this.options).filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
}
```

The amount you can bind value to

> options[selectedOpt]

getting default value from dictionary and setting on input

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Courses" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="selectedOpt">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Amount" [value]="options[selectedOpt]">
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, everything is working fine. But by default in the input field (i,e Amount) is displaying as `undefined`.

Comment: You can create a get property 

     `public get amount(): number {
        return this.options[this.selectedOpt] ? this.options[this.selectedOpt] : 0;
     } `

and bind amount to amount input `<input matInput placeholder="Amount" [value]="amount">`

Answer (score 0):

Please use Below code

HTML

```
 <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="optionSelected($event, row, column, rowIndex)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>

<input matInput placeholder="Amount" [(ngModel)]="amount">
```

in TS

```
  optionSelected(event){
    if(event.option.value == 'Physics')
      this.amount = 2000;
    if(event.option.value == 'Maths')
      this.amount = 5000;
    if (event.option.value == 'Biology')
      this.amount = 10000;
  }
```

Comment: He's currently using reactive forms, not template-driven forms. These should not be mixed.

Comment: Ya i am using reactive forms @p4r1

Answer (score 0):

Hi for undefined you are getting just change the piece of code

```
enter code here[value]="options[selectedOpt] == undefined ? '' : options[selectedOpt]"
```

Comment: There is an edit request pending here. To editor : @osiris85 : you tell in your edit description that null is not checked. But actually, `== undefined` checks for both `null` and `undefined` in JavaScript (as `== null` does, by the way). If you remove the `== undefined`, you are checking for the value to be truthy or falsy (falsy are `0`, `''`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `false`), which may be or not be what is needed. I did n't approve nor rejected the edit, I was not sure of this being relevant or not.